# How to join Minute based time-range with Date using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` looks like this:

```
DateTimeVal            Open 
2017-01-01 17:00:00    5.1532    
2017-01-01 17:01:00    5.3522 
2017-01-01 17:02:00    5.4535    
2017-01-01 17:03:00    5.3567    
2017-01-01 17:04:00    5.1512 
....
```

It is a `Minute` based data

The `Time` value starts from `17:00:00` however I want to only change the `Time` value to start from `00:00:00` as a `Minute` based data and up to `23:59:00`

The current `Time` starts at `17:00:00` and increments per `Minute` and ends on `16:59:00`. The total `row` value is `1440` so I can confirm that it is a `Minute` based `24 Hour` data

My new `df` should looks like this:

```
DateTimeVal            Open 
2017-01-01 00:00:00    5.1532    
2017-01-01 00:01:00    5.3522 
2017-01-01 00:02:00    5.4535    
2017-01-01 00:03:00    5.3567    
2017-01-01 00:04:00    5.1512 
....
```

Here, we did not change anything except the `Time` part.

**What did I do?**

My logic was to remove the `Time` and then populate with new `Time`

Here is what I did:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTimeVal'].astype(str).str.rsplit(' ', 1).str[0], dayfirst=True)
```

But I do not know how to add the new `Time` data. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

How about subtracting 17 hours from your `DateTimeVal`:

```
df['DateTimeVal'] -= pd.Timedelta(hours=17)
```